# How to call ILOG rule from a .jar file that is exported from RES?

Tags: java, ilog

I am working on ILOG Jrules7.1. I have written the rules and deployed in RES. 
I am able to call the rules using a webservice. I am getting the expected results as well.

But my client requirement is to export the rules from RES as jar and add this jar in a web application.

I should be able to call this rules with in the web application, without hitting the RES.

Answer (score 2):

It's the Rules Execution Server (RES) that actually executes the rules, so you still need to call that.  You can export the rules as a jar, but that just allows you to install them into another RES, not execute them by themselves.

When you say "I am able to call the rules using a webservice," you're actually calling the RES and telling it to execute your rules, not calling the rules directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a Java Client for Rules based applications.
This Client would hold the rulset.jar, configurable via ra.xml based on your settings, ( File/DB based persistence )

You can refer to the steps mentioned above at this link

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.7.1/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.res.developing/topics/tsk_res_client_pojo.html

Hope it helps!!!